# Is there any point in using a non-null IV for AES-GCM if the key is only used once?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I understand that *re-using* a key without a unique IV is a deadly sin, but what if there‘s the guarantee that the key is only used for encrypting and decrypting one dataset?

I was thinking about generating a longer random sequence, splitting it up in two parts, using one part as the key and the other as the IV. But does that give me *any* advantage over just using a null IV? Again: The key is only used once.

Comment: Technically not. But the odds of that going wrong are cryptonomical.

Comment: if keys are slightly non-random, using part as IVs could leak implementation details.

Comment: This might help you since GCM uses CTR [Using 0 nonce for AES-256 in CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77772/18298). And note that the Authentication tag also uses a new key.